# Workflow reports

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, workflow-activity, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am exploring SharePoint Online (Power Automate) for the workflow development. There is a requirement to show historical workflow information as a report so that previous interactions with the users can be captured.

Could you please suggest any existing feature of Power Automate or how to do customization for it?

I really appreciate any pointers or suggestions.

Thank you very much for your support and time.

Please note: I am a beginner to the SharePoint Online and dot net framework.

Regards,
AK

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script to get reports for Microsoft Flows:

```
Get-AdminFlow | Export-Csv -Path "E:\Powershell OutPut\FlowExport.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Install the required modules before you run the cmdlet:

```
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.Administration.PowerShell
Install-Module -Name Microsoft.PowerApps.PowerShell -AllowClobber
```

Reference: [Get-AdminFlow.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powerapps.administration.powershell/get-adminflow?view=pa-ps-latest)

And another sample script for workflows in case you need it: [SharePoint Online: Get Workflow Inventory using PowerShell.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/05/sharepoint-online-get-workflow-inventory-using-powershell.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, Chelsea for your suggestion. Do you have any pointers for Microsoft Power Automate workflow customization documentation/resources? Thank you again.

Comment: I found this link for documentation https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/getting-started. I am looking for the documentation where I can find how to customized a flow step/task by code within a workflow. Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: @user95345 While Power Automate is intended to provide no-code solution for automation, you can use Custom Connectors to do customization from the outside: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/
See a sample here using Common Data Service platforms integration: https://jonasr.app/2020/09/pro-code-escape/

Comment: Thank you very much Chelsea. I request a help on another topic where I didn't get a response from anyone. I am looking to preview XML file in Sharepoint online using XSLT. Could you please suggest any ideas or pointers? I really appreciate it? Thank you very much.